# keep same domain in the same directory

Tags: linux, wget

If I do the following

```
wget -E -H -k -K -p http://example.com
```

It would create a directory example.com and if there were any files referenced with a www.example.com then it would create a www.example.com directory. How can I tell wget that www.example.com and example.com are the same thing?

Comment: +1: Actually example.com and www.example.com are two different things but i wonder if there is something like a compound directory for the default mapping in the zonefile and the mapped domain

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround against creating two directories would be to create a symbolic link before starting:

```
ln -s example.com www.example.com
```

But I suppose wget will still download the same document twice if it exists on both domains, overwriting the earlier one. A general-purpose "these URLs are equivalent" option seems to still be missing for wget.